# Visual Studio Code not executing Python file

Tags: python, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

On my notebook, Visual Studio Code (VS Code) does not execute my python files anymore.

Yesterday it worked fine, then VS Code suggested me to update powershell from version 5.2 to 7. I did the update, know if I open my python file an try to run without debugging, the script is not executed.

Can someone help me with this issue?

My script for testing is only: `print("Hello World")`

What looks a bit strange for me is, that in the bottom right corner it shows the python version `3.6.10`:[image]

If I go to command prompt an choose `Command Prompt`, it shows python version `3.6.10` too:
[image]
[image]

But if I go to powershell (The first selection ind the picture above) it shows me another python version:
[image]

I hope someone can help me, I have no idea what to do anymore. Thanks!

Best regards,
Daniel

Added later:
Control bar which shows up for a very short time (Not even a second):
[image]

Comment: Can you describe your problem in detail? What method is used to run the code, and what is the result of running the code? No response or other error message?

Comment: I do have created a test.py file, which only includes 'print("Hello World")'. If I run the code with Strg+F5, nothing happens (And no error message is shown). Only the control bar (I added a screenshot in the original post) is shown for a very short time.

Comment: Is there no result output in the terminal? Try reinstalling the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) or install a [pre-release version](https://imgur.com/a/xKOShpI). Or reinstall [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) after uninstalling.

Comment: I haven‘t upgraded the python version somit does not work at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The **python3.6** version is no longer supported in the latest debugger version.

Please use the new python version. Or install the historical version debugger.